# Store txt with inconsistent column number into a table

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have this txt files which contains data points stored as such:

```
fbbh-b-an86 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 71 71 71 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 138 138 138 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 16 16 16 16 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 84 84 84 84 84 136 136 136 136 136 136 136 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 115 115 115 115 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
fbbh-b-an87 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 42 42 42 42 42 92 92 92 92 92 92 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 110 68 68 68 68 68 68 68 80 80 80 111 111 111 111 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 107 107 107 107 107 107 107 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
fbbh-b-an88 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 66 66 66 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 52 52 52 52 111 111 111 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 114 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 50 50 50 50 50 50 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 35 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 127 127 127 127 127 127 127 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 138 68 68 68 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 108 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The name at the beginning is a name associated to the data point, and the numbers are the data points.  The number of data points depends on the name, so the number of columns aren't the same.

I need to store these sets data points in a certain order in a numpy array, in which i though storing it in a map would make life easier, as i just would need to make a lookup based on the name to find get the set of data points i need.  But how do i do that with such a file..

I tried something like this:

import csv

```
data = open(data_points,"rb")
dict = csv.DictReader(data,delimiter=" ")
```

but this resulted in `None` appearing and each entry not being able to look up based on the name..

```
{'': None, '115': None, '38': None, '16': None, 'fbbh-b-an86': 'fbbh-b-an87', '32': None, '50': None, '1': None, '123': None, '110': '110', '71': None, '138': '107', '84': None, '136': None}
{'': '1', '115': '29', '38': '1', '16': '1', 'fbbh-b-an86': 'fbbh-b-an88', '32': '1', '50': '29', '1': '1', '123': '55', '110': '101', '71': '35', '138': '114', None: ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '127', '127', '127', '127', '127', '127', '127', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '138', '68', '68', '68', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '108', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '99', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', ''], '84': '42', '136': '42'}
{'': '32', '115': '38', '38': '74', '16': '71', 'fbbh-b-an86': 'fbbh-b-an89', '32': '71', '50': '38', '1': '32', '123': '1', '110': '24', '71': '71', '138': '1', None: ['32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '16', '84', '84', '84', '136', '136', '136', '136', '136', '123', '123', '123', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '110', '44', '44', '44', '44', '128', '128', '128', '128', '128', '16', '16', '16', '92', '92', '92', '92', '92', '116', '116', '116', '116', '71', '71', '71', '71', '71', '90', '90', '90', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '54', '68', '68', '68', '68', '56', '56', '56', '56', '56', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '116', '71', '71', '71', '71', '90', '90', '90', '90', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '28', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '91', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', ''], '84': '71', '136': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DictReader does not seem appropriate to me here, as your data is not organized with each column having a meaning, but rather each line having a name and some arbitrary data.

Are you trying to get a map where map['fbbh-b-an86'] would give you the first line of points ? If so this should do the trick:

```
import csv    
map = {}
with open(data_points, 'rb') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
  for row in reader:
    name = row[0]
    map[name] = row[1:]
print map
```